# Copy assets of library with Yarn Plug'n'Play

Tags: yarnpkg

I have codes to copy assets when building. I'm wondering what's the best way to do the same thing with [Yarn Plug'n'Play](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/pull/101) since node_modules does not exist.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/cmaps/', to: 'static/cmaps/' },
]),
```

`yarn cache dir` tells me the directory and also there's a package location in `.pnp.js`.

```
  ["pdfjs-dist", new Map([
    ["2.0.943", {
      packageLocation: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../Library/Caches/Yarn/v3/npm-pdfjs-dist-2.0.943-32fb9a2d863df5a1d89521a0b3cd900c16e7edde/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/"),
```

Should I somehow parse the file and copy as I did before? Or is there better way?

Comment: I think parsing yarn.lock by https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/tree/master/packages/lockfile and get sha1 then it can detect the cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Yarn Plug n' Play, you can get the base path to your `from` directory using `require.resolve('name-of-package')`. In this case, it's something like

```js
const path = require('path');
const modulePath = require.resolve('pdfjs-dist');
const fromPath = path.join(modulePath, 'cmaps');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `require.resolve` is correct, but depending on the package it can result in this error

> Error: Qualified path resolution failed: we looked for the following paths, but none could be accessed.

The [CopyWebpackPlugin documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#yarn-workspaces-and-monorepos) suggests the following snippet when working with yarn workspaces or monorepos.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: `${path.dirname(
            require.resolve(`${moduleName}/package.json`)
          )}/target`,
          to: "target",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```